# My Selenium webdriver doesn’t work on cTrader

Tags: python, selenium

Why is my Selenium webdriver not working?

I would like to log in automatically on https://ct.spotware.com/. But Selenium can't find the HTML class for the login box.

For this, I wrote this little script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")

driver.get("https://ct.spotware.com/")
time.sleep(10)
Login = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_a _b _gc _gw _dq _dx _gd _cw _em _cy _gx _fu _gy _fv _fy _fw _fx _db _ge _gf _gz _gg _gh _gi _gj _gk _gl _gm _gn")
```

[Ctrader HTM class reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7PLG.png)

The error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._a _b _gc _gw _dq _dx _gd _cw _em _cy _gx _fu _gy _fv _fy _fw _fx _db _ge _gf _gz _gg _gh _gi _gj _gk _gl _gm _gn"}
```

Somehow the whole site doesn't work with Selenium. On other sites, like Wikipedia, my script works perfectly. Just not on [cTrader](https://en.everybodywiki.com/CTrader).

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here:

1. All these class name values `_a _b _gc _gw _dq _dx _gd _cw _em _cy _gx _fu _gy _fv _fy _fw _fx _db _ge _gf _gz _gg _gh _gi _gj _gk _gl _gm _gn` are multiple separate class names. To use them you need to use CSS Selector or XPath.
2. The sequence of all the above class names looks to be fragile. You should use another, more stable and more clear locator.
3. Instead of hardcoded sleep you should use WebdriverWait explicit waits.
4. You need to close the cookies banner
5. And insert the user name and passwords
   Anyway, the code below clicks the login button itself.
   Please see the code below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

s = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://ct.spotware.com/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The spaces in your class name are not handled by Selenium. The following may help.

```
Login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._a._b._gc._gw._dq._dx._gd _cw._em._cy._gx._fu._gy._fv._fy._fw._fx._db._ge._gf._gz._gg._gh._gi._gj._gk._gl._gm._gn")
```

However, upon examining your site, I'd recommend using a CSS selector such as this:

```
'input[placeholder="Enter your email or cTrader ID"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to correctly select the elements and login:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time as t
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://ct.spotware.com/'
browser.get(url) 

login_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder="Enter your email or cTrader ID"]')))
pass_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder="Enter your password"]')))
submit_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text() = "Log In"]')))
login_field.send_keys('username')
pass_field.send_keys('bad_pass')
submit_button.click()
print('clicked')
```

Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/